# How to replace word with hyperlink?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, regex-group

Starting with an example, I have some keywords like

> Narendra Modi, Modi, India, Speech, Parliament

And I have a story with text

> Narendra Modi will give a speech in the parliament of India.

Now I want my regex to replace the keyword with the hyperlink in the story.

> `<a>Narendra Modi</a> will give speech in the <a>parliament</a> of <a>India.</a>`

My Code for this is

```
var tagArray = bodykeywords.Split(',').ToList();
foreach (var tag in tagArray.OrderBy(a => a.Length))
{
    var replaceTag = tag.Replace("(", "");
    replaceTag = replaceTag.Replace(")", "");
    DataDesc = Regex.Replace(DataDesc, "\"" + replaceTag.Trim() + "\"", " <a href=\"/news?tag=" + replaceTag.Trim() + "\">\"" + replaceTag.Trim() + "\"</a> ");
    DataDesc = Regex.Replace(DataDesc, " " + replaceTag.Trim() + ", ", " <a href=\"/news?tag=" + replaceTag.Trim() + "\">" + replaceTag.Trim() + "</a>, ");
    DataDesc = Regex.Replace(DataDesc, " " + replaceTag.Trim() + " ", " <a href=\"/news?tag=" + replaceTag.Trim() + "\">" + replaceTag.Trim() + "</a> ");

}
```

**Problem is I am not able to replace the word with full stop like India in the given example and Word with repetition like Narendra Modi, Modi in the keyword.**

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625).

Comment: BTW: The full-stop should be _outside_ of the link, not inside.

Comment: @UweKeim So how I can achieve this?

Comment: @UweKeim Full stop should be outside

Comment: I would recommend another pass, where you simply replace `.</a>` with `</a>.` you do not need regex for this fix